# Can't import database through phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, nginx, phpmyadmin, apache2

When I try upload database (794 kb) I have error:

```
No data was received to import. Either no file name was submitted, or the file size exceeded the maximum size permitted by your PHP configuration. See FAQ 1.16.
```

I have read many answer for this error but I can not find and decision and answers that works for me.

My server:

**Ubuntu 12.10 Server**

**Apache/2.2.22 ( apache2-mpm-itk)**;

**MySQL client version: 5.5.27**;

**phpmyadmin 3.4.11.1deb1**;

**nginx/1.2.1**;

**PHP 5.4.6**;

Configuration phpmyadmin in  **/etc/nginx/default**

```
 location /phpmyadmin {

                root /usr/share/phpmyadmin;
                index index.php;

                proxy_pass http://backend/phpmyadmin;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
                proxy_connect_timeout 120;
                proxy_send_timeout 120;
                proxy_read_timeout 180;

}
```

**php.ini config**

```
file_uploads = On
upload_tmp_dir = /var/tmp
upload_max_filesize = 128M
max_file_uploads = 30
post_max_size = 128M
```

Thank you!

Comment: if you do not select your file through `browse` button in phpmyadmin,you'll get this message. is it your case?

Comment: check if your temp folder had write access from php

Comment: @Amir no, I select file through browse button in phpmyadmin, and when I submit, I have this error.

Comment: Do you have access to MySQL through the command? You could just import it from there

Comment: @Raidenace I made `chmod -R 777 /var/lib/phpmyadmin/tmp/` and all works, but I don't now if it is good practice and if it is secure.

Comment: @EddieJaoude yes I have, but it is very interesting why this don't work with phpmyadmin )

Comment: @denys281 - Usually tmp folders do have relaxed permissions because they are just transient placeholders of data. Having said that, if you are working in local host that is fine. In server side, the permissions for such directories will be correctly set up by sys admins. Am glad it helped fix your issue..

Answer (score 5):

Thanks [@denys281](https://stackoverflow.com/users/606907/denys281), that helped me:

```
chmod -R 777 /var/lib/phpmyadmin/tmp
```

Comment: This line of code is gonna be on my note book right now. It saved me a lot of time! Thank you very much!

Comment: This creates a security risk because the directory would then be accessible for any PHP script running on the server.

Answer (score 2):

```
chown apache-user /var/lib/phpmyadmin/tmp
```

Replace **apache-user** with the user configured in **/etc/apache2/envvars**. Look for these settings:

```
export APACHE_RUN_USER=apache-user
export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=apache-group
```

That way you will give permissions for the user running on the web server access to the temp directory, without making it 777 (open to all users).

Comment: Thank you for this. This fixes the problem if: you've changed your APACHE_RUN_USER to something other than www-data (like I did, to clear up permission + upload issues developing on localhost).

Answer (score 0):

decrease the "upload_max_filesize = 128M" by 1 MB or so . this trick will work

Answer (score 0):

In my base php.ini configuration I had disabled file_uploads and limited the upload size so then on for each vhost these values are modified if need be.

PMA uses its own apache configuration which is found at:

```
/etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf
```

So to enable file uploads with a 10Mb file size limit, I edited the file like this:

```
<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin>
    Options SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    DirectoryIndex index.php

    # Enable File loads if required
    php_admin_flag file_uploads On
    php_admin_flag post_max_size 10M
    php_admin_flag upload_max_filesize 10M

    <IfModule mod_php5.c>
    ...
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_php.c>
    ...
    </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

Don't forget to reload the Apache server configuration:

Ubuntu < 16.04

```
service apache2 reload
```

Ubuntu = 16.04

```
systemctl reload apache2
```