# No data was received to import

Tags: php, mysql, import, phpmyadmin

I want to import database in phpmyadmin but i got error like this... "No data was received to import. Either no file name was submitted, or the file size exceeded the maximum size permitted by your PHP configuration."  my file size is 558kb, on live server

Comment: did you check the extension of the data to be imported?

Answer (score 6):

If your database size is greater than 2MB then such problem will occur,
goto php.ini, 
then find 
`upload_max_filesize = 2M`
now replace 2M to `upload_max_filesize = 10M` now no problem unless your database size is less than 10MB. You can set value as per your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Check file /etc/apache2/envvars for following lines:

```
export APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data
```

export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=www-data

If there is different user set than www-data it may cause problem like described.

Comment: This was the clue to the problem for me. Solution is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29281046/835996

Answer (score 0):

This FAQ entry describes some PHP parameters that need to be correct for file uploads:
https://phpmyadmin.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html?highlight=upload_max_filesize#i-cannot-upload-big-dump-files-memory-http-or-timeout-problems