# phpmyadmin hangs when importing a database

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to import a database into a new PhpMyAdmin install but I don't get very far. Pressing the "go" button just infinitely shows a spinning wheel and

> Please be patient, the file is being uploaded. Details about the upload are not available

but there is no upload taking place.

- It's not a large database (~200kb) so that isn't the issue.
- I've got a temp folder specified & uploading turned on in php.ini

Thanks for any support in helping me figure out why it won't proceed.

Comment: ok, i'll need more info about this issue. Are you on your localhost or remote server (with root access or so)? What's the phpMyAdmin version? Is the DB you're importing compressed file and what settings do you have on the import screen? If you're in a rush for the DB to be imported, you can do it straight away via CLI and try to figure this out afterwards.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your time. 

1. This is on a remote unmanaged VPS I own (so full root access). 

2. It's version 3.4.11.1deb2+deb7u1. 

3. The DB isn't compressed, just a typical .sql file.

4. [These are all the setting options I see](http://i.imgur.com/Rl5MYtz.png) (i.e the standard options).

I've already since imported it using the command line, but I would like to figure out why I can't do it from the webpage in the meantime :)

Comment: hm it all looks good, can you check if you have write privileges to a temp folder (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/22036646/2609269); do you have any other project on the server that uploads files via PHP successfully?